# Find a primitive element for the extension $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt3,e^{{\pi i/4}})/\mathbb Q$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Find a primitive element for the extension $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt3,e^{{\pi i/4}})/\mathbb Q$.

I was guessing the primitive element is $i+\sqrt3+e^{{\pi i/4}}$. It is obvious that $\mathbb Q(i+\sqrt3+e^{{\pi i/4}})\subset \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt3,e^{{\pi i/4}})$.

To show that the converse inclusion, we need to show $i,\sqrt3$ and $\text{}e^{{\pi i/4}}$ are contained in $Q(i+\sqrt3+e^{{\pi i/4}}).$

I have no clue how to do it. Can any one help me on this question?

Answer (score 2):

One can see that $$\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{3},e^{{\pi i/4}})=\mathbb Q(e^{{2\pi i/3}},e^{{\pi i/4}})=\mathbb Q(e^{{2\pi i/3}})\cdot \mathbb Q(e^{{\pi i/4}}) \subseteq \mathbb{C}.$$
That  is,  we have  the composite of the cyclotomic extensions $\mathbb Q(\zeta_3)$ and  $\mathbb Q(\zeta_8)$ (where $\zeta_n$ denotes a  $n$-th primitive root of unity). The theory of cyclotomic extensions (see p. 6 in here:
http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cyclotomic.pdf ) tells us that this composite
is generated by $\zeta_{lcm(3,8)}=\zeta_{24}$. Therefore

$$\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{3},e^{{\pi i/4}})=\mathbb Q(e^{{\pi i/12}}).$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you help me for the extension $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt2,e^{2\pi i/3})$. I got stuck in this problem.

Comment: isn't this field the same as $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{3},e^{{\pi i/4}})$?

Comment: I think it's different.

Comment: Let's see: Can you explicitly express $e^{\pi i/4}$  and $e^{\pi 2i/3}$ in terms of complex numbers ($\sqrt 2, \sqrt3, i,$ etc.)?